# IBAction not fired sometimes after UIGestureRecognizer handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, hittest

I'm trying to track hits on UI elements (tap and long press)  using `UIGestureRecognizer`. After hit was tracked (let's say logged via `NSLog`) UI element should do it's job.

I'm creating gesture recognizers like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer] alloc initWithTarget:self action:(OnGesture:)]
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tap.delegate = self;
[view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer] alloc initWithTarget:self action:(OnGesture:)]
longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
longPress.delegate = self;
[view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

I've overridden some gesture recognizer methods:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)_recognizer shouldReceiveTouch(UITouch*)_touch
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)_recognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)_otherRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Inside the gesture recognizer handler, I'm trying to find the exact subview of the tap by using the `hitTest` method.

```
-(void)OnGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)_recognizer
{
    if([_recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded])
    {
        if([_recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]
            || [_recognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class])
        {
            CGPoint location = [_recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:_recognizer.view];                

            // my problem occurs here:
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            UIView* hitView = [_recognizer.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
             NSLog(@"Hit on view: %@", hitView);
         }
    }
}
```

---

### So my problem is:

Sometimes (1 out of 10 cases) when I press the UIButton `OnGesture` method fires, but the IBAction of the "Touch Up Inside" event of that button is not firing.

---

But when I comment out `hitTest` call:

```
//UIView* hitView = [_recognizer.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
```

the bug stops being reproducible. IBAction always gets called.

---

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

P.S. there could be some typos in the sample code above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:), in order for it to work:

> This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01. This method does not take the view’s content into account when determining a hit. Thus, a view can still be returned even if the specified point is in a transparent portion of that view’s content.

So you might wanna do `self.someSubview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`